# How do I run mp4 videos in the terminal?, like the video shows on the terminal rather then the a new window

Tags: python, image, video, terminal

#### How do I run videos directly in the terminal, with python and vscode.

How do I run MP4 videos directly in the terminal without *any window popping*, I also want to run **pictures** in the terminal as well only in the python terminal.

I tried using vs codes image supported, How do I do this, thanks for the help!

I need something like this, It works but the video looks bad and filled with square pixels

Comment: A terminal is a text interface. How do you imagine the videos to be displayed without graphical interface?

Comment: @KlausD. Somehow I want to

Comment: A tool like Jupyter can run Python code and also view pictures/video. But that's not a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to show images and videos in the terminal. The terminal is a text-based interface, so the only possible method of this is to open it in a new window.